# How can I add a script to nautilus for running selected file as administrator?

Tags: nautilus, scripts, administrator

How can I add a script to nautilus for running selected file as administrator (not open as administrator)? And if it is possible, I want to run this file as administrator without entering my password.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Information on using sudo or gksudo on scripts without password

You need to do the following, on the terminal type `sudo visudo` and add a line like this at the end of the file specifying the commands you want to run without typing the sudo password:

```
<yourusername> hostname=NOPASSWD: <command1>, <command2>
```

Now you can run the specified commands without password as long as you type that command with `sudo`.

ie: lets you want to run `shutdown -r now` without having to type sudo password everytime and your username is 'joedoe'

1. type `sudo visudo` on a terminal
2. Add `joedoe hostname=NOPASSWD: shutdown -r now` as a new line at the end of the file
3. on your script you can then use `sudo shutdown -r now` without having to type the sudo password.

To create a scrip use your favorite editor to create a `<nameofyourscript>.sh` with the contents:

```
#! /bin/bash

sudo <commandsyouwanttorun1>
<commandsyouwanttorun2>
sudo<commandsyouwanttorun3>
```

Use sudo to call commands that need it, it wont ask for password as long as you added that on the `NOPASSWD: <commmand1>, <command2>, etc` line in `visudo`.

After that you need to make it executable with: `sudo chmod 755 <nameofyourscript>.sh`.

Now you can run your script using `sh <nameofyourscript>.sh` on a terminal, by double clicking on it and selecting `run` on the dialog box or put them in your `~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts/` which then will be available on your `scripts` menu when you right click on nautilus:

[image]

### Create a right-click "Open as admin" without password

To create a scrip that opens files using administrator permissions by right clicking on them and making it so that no passwords will be asked create a script with the following:

```
#! /bin/bash
for file in $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS; do
gksudo "gnome-open $file" &
done
```

Save it on your `~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts/`, make it executable with `sudo chmod 755 ~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts/<nameofyourscript>.sh`, using `sudo visudo` add the line `<yourusername> ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/gnome-open` and save the file.

You should be able to right-click a file, move to your scripts folder and selecting the script you just created to open that file using root permistions. `gnome-open` will handle the file type as good as possible.

[image: click on your openasadmin script]

[image: done!]

Comment: Thanks for answer! But there was a little misunderstanding: What I need was "run as admin" not "open as admin", so I chanched the line `"gksudo "gnome-open $file" &"` to `"gksudo "gnome-terminal -x $file" &"`

Comment: Sure, the "first chapter" would give you enough info to do whatever you want to ;) glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Nautilus scripts usually are to be placed in `$HOME/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts/` and need to be executable. That being said, the follow script should do, what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS='
'

for file in $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS; do
    gksudo -k "sh -c 'chmod +x $file; $file'"
done
```

You can access that script from nautilus by right clicking on the file, hovering over the script menu and then clicking on the filename of the script in `$HOME/.gonme2/nautilus-scritps/`. You still have to enter your password though.

There is no **secure** way you can do this with arbitrary files without entering your password. For special commands the process is described in [brunopereira81's post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65460/how-can-i-add-a-script-to-nautilus-for-running-selected-file-as-administrator/65464#65464) here and uses sudo but depending on the commands will lead to a vulnerable system. If you don't care (and I strongly advice against this) you can set `ALL` commands to use `NOPASSWD` and replace `gksudo` by just `sudo`.

Comment: Why do you permanently chmod the file?

Comment: because it was the quick way :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Nautilus extension. [Nautilus-gksu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/nautilus-gksu) [image: Install nautilus-gksu].

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-gksu
```

Installing it adds a 'Open as administrator' entry in your nautilus right-click menu.

[image]

When you need to open any files with root permission, you just have to right-click on the file, select 'Open as Administrator', as simple as that.

For more cool extensions visit : http://www.techdrivein.com/2010/09/6-useful-nautilus-extensions-and.html

Comment: "Open as administrator" still asks for a password.

Comment: Ya it does.. :)