# How to elevate a programs privileges on the fly?

Tags: permissions

I'm relatively new to Linux (coming from Windows) and one thing that always bugs me is how restrictive the system is. For example I'm trying to install Sublime Text 2 into /opt/ right now, but when I open the tar archive and try to extract the folder, I get the following error:

> You don't have the right permissions to extract archives in the folder "file:///opt"

In Windows or Mac I usually would have some sort of option "As Administrator..", which would elevate the privileges instantly (possibly prompting a password) and then perform the operation.

With Linux I seem to be stuck to somehow figure out the Archive Manager's exact name and then run it with sudo from the terminal. In the menu there isn't even a right-click "Run as root.." option or anything similar.

Isn't there an easier way of handling this in general?

I'm running Xubuntu with XFCE but I had this problem with every desktop distribution I tried so far.

Comment: If you are new to Linux, why are you installing applications manually? If at all possible, use the Ubuntu repositories. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu . To install  Sublime Text 2 see http://askubuntu.com/questions/172698/how-do-i-install-sublime-text-2. For permissions see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions. And for root access see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to take a look at this thread which explains how you can add a right-click sudo style script 
[How can I add a script to nautilus for running selected file as administrator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65460/how-can-i-add-a-script-to-nautilus-for-running-selected-file-as-administrator)